# How to run a Python shell in azure app service

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

In [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/), I knew there is a [Kudu debug console](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/super-secret-kudu-debug-console-for-azure-web-sites/) like the following:

[image]

Can be used to trigger commands in that console.

but I found this console will be gotten stuck if I trigger a python shell like this:

D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts>python.exe

[image]

Is it possible having an interactive python shell under azure app service like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not something that will work in Kudu Console today. The problem is that Kudu Console is not a true shell, and does have some limitations when it comes to running interactive commands.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can run python with the command flag like so

```
d:\home>python -c "import os;print(os.environ)"
```

although unless there is a way or trick to create multline on Kudu Console you would be limited to python without indentation